# Router with render not passing props in another component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have 2 class component `PhoneDirectory.js` and `App.js`

```
class PhoneDirectory extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<App />} render={(props) => <App {...props} name="test" />} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  };
}

export default PhoneDirectory;
```

The other Class Component

```
class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    console.log("value:", this.props.name);
    return (
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here in App.js I am getting undefined in console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `react-router-dom@6` there are no longer `component` and `render` and `children` function props, they were replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX. You can pass additional props.

Example:

```
<Route path="/" element={<App name="test" />} />
```

...

```
class App extends Component{
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("value:", this.props.name);
  }

  render() {
    return ....;
  }
}

export default App;
```